# Converting arrow function to regular function - For use in Google Tag Manager

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager, arrow-functions

I want to use that script in GTM:

```js
<script>
var isOverIFrame = false
var iframes = window.document.querySelectorAll('iframe');
function trackIframeClicks(frames){
  window.addEventListener('blur',function(e) {
    frames.forEach(function (frame, index) {
      if (frame.mouseOver) {
        window.dataLayer.push({
          'event': 'ifameClick',
          'frameSource': frame.src
        });
        // console.log(frame.src);
      }
    })
  });
}
function setListeners (frames) {
  frames.forEach(function(frame) {
    frame.mouseOver = false
    frame.addEventListener('mouseenter', () =>{
      frame.mouseOver = true
      // console.log('mouse in iframe')
    });
    frame.addEventListener('mouseleave', () =>{
      frame.mouseOver = false
      // console.log('mouse out of iframe')
    });
  })
}
setListeners(iframes);
trackIframeClicks(iframes);
</script>
```

When trying to publish it I get the following error:

Error in line 20 & 24, character 42: This language feature is only supported for ECMASCRIPT_2015 mode or better: arrow function.

Can someone please help rewriting the function so it will work without arrow functions?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I recommend this page, you can see for yourself how es6 is converted to es5 [babeljs.io](https://babeljs.io/repl)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    function setListeners (frames) {
  frames.forEach(function(frame) {
    frame.mouseOver = false
    frame.addEventListener('mouseenter',function enter (){
      frame.mouseOver = true
      // console.log('mouse in iframe')
    });
    frame.addEventListener('mouseleave',function leave () {
      frame.mouseOver = false
      // console.log('mouse out of iframe')
    });
  })
}
```

Comment: Not much explanation, hope this is a good eye opener though. :) EC5!

Comment: Oh you can too set /*jshint esversion: 8 */
for error function top of your project and 'use strict'; in your upper scope functions. If looking for higher support but EC5 is dope.

Comment: No problem, hope you see what all I did there. Quick switch! :D

Answer (score 0):

```js
// An arrow function
() => {
  ...
}
// is shorthand syntactic sugar for
(function () { 
  ...
}).bind(this)
```

But since you don't need the binding to `this` you can drop that and just use a normal function.

```js
function () {
   ...
}
```